# error occurred while installing semacode (0.7.5) gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

Issue while installing semacode gem from gemfile. is there a way to resolve this? i am running bundle install. Is this a issue with my machine or a gem issue? This issue did happen for the first time on my machine when i tried to run the application locally.

Using semacode 0.7.5 from https://github.com/toretore/semacode.git (at master@4e31e0b)

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.



make "DESTDIR=" clean

.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/semacode-4e31e0b79a1a/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling reedsol.c
compiling semacode.c
semacode.c:61:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'iec16022init' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  iec16022init(&semacode->width, &semacode->height, message);
  ^
semacode.c:96:28: warning: 'bzero' call operates on objects of type 'semacode_t' (aka 'struct semacode_t') while the size is based on a different type 'semacode_t *' (aka 'struct
semacode_t *') [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]
    bzero(semacode, sizeof(semacode));
          ~~~~~~~~         ^~~~~~~~
semacode.c:96:28: note: did you mean to dereference the argument to 'sizeof' (and multiply it by the number of elements)?
    bzero(semacode, sizeof(semacode));
                           ^~~~~~~~
semacode.c:129:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  encode_string(semacode, StringValueLen(message), StringValuePtr(message));
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./semacode.h:26:27: note: expanded from macro 'StringValueLen'
#define StringValueLen(s) RSTRING_LEN(RB_STRING_VALUE(s))
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
semacode.c:129:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  encode_string(semacode, StringValueLen(message), StringValuePtr(message));
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./semacode.h:26:27: note: expanded from macro 'StringValueLen'
#define StringValueLen(s) RSTRING_LEN(RB_STRING_VALUE(s))
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:995:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
semacode.c:239:20: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
    semacode->data == NULL;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
semacode.c:239:20: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
    semacode->data == NULL;
                   ^~
                   =
semacode.c:243:44: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  DATA_PTR(self) = encode_string(semacode, StringValueLen(message), StringValuePtr(message));
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./semacode.h:26:27: note: expanded from macro 'StringValueLen'
#define StringValueLen(s) RSTRING_LEN(RB_STRING_VALUE(s))
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:994:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:990:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
semacode.c:243:44: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  DATA_PTR(self) = encode_string(semacode, StringValueLen(message), StringValuePtr(message));
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./semacode.h:26:27: note: expanded from macro 'StringValueLen'
#define StringValueLen(s) RSTRING_LEN(RB_STRING_VALUE(s))
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:995:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
6 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [semacode.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in .rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/semacode-4e31e0b79a1a for inspection.
Results logged to .rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.3.0-static/semacode-4e31e0b79a1a/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing semacode (0.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  semacode
```

Comment: What version of the Xcode command line tools do you have installed? `gcc -v` will return something like v11.x or v12.x. I've seen some similar issues on macOS that have only started since v12 was released. If you have v12 you can try downgrading to v11.5 from https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.5/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.5.dmg and retrying the gem installation.

Comment: Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)

Comment: Thanks, downgrading Xcode did resolve the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
gem install semacode -v 0.7.5 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Here is more information:

> Clang now reports an error when you use a function without an explicit declaration when building C or Objective-C code for macOS (-Werror=implicit-function-declaration flag is on). This additional error detection unifies Clang’s behavior for iOS/tvOS and macOS 64-bit targets for this diagnostic. (49917738)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes

Comment: This is great! Those flags can also be used with Bundler:  `bundle config build.semacode-ruby19 --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some similar issues on macOS that have only started since v12 was released. If you have v12 you can try downgrading to v11.5 from download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/… and retrying the gem installation

credits - @anothermh